# Woocommerce webhook to Yii2 API returns 401

Tags: api, woocommerce, yii2, webhooks

i try to receive modification of stock product when a product is bought on a woocommerce website via a webhook on woocommerce to my yii2 app.

So far i receive an 401 error.

for info, i try to connect with an access_token. With postman and with woocommerce
i get the 401 error but no more data, i don't understand how i should connect.

Also, i have auttomatic/woocommerce on my Yii2 App, as the other way, i succeed to update woocommerce products from yii2 :)

this is my api controller :

```
<?php
namespace app\modules\api\controllers;
use Yii;
use yii\rest\ActiveController;
//use yii\web\Response;
use yii\filters\auth\HttpBearerAuth;
use app\modules\api\resources\Cors;
use app\modules\api\resources\ProductsResource;

class ProductsController extends ActiveController
{
  public $modelClass = ProductsResource::class;
  Public $enableCsrfValidation = false;
  public static function allowedDomains() {
      return [$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], '*'];
  }

  public function behaviors()
  {
        $behaviors = parent::behaviors();
        $behaviors['authenticator']['except'] = ['options'];
        $auth = $behaviors['authenticator'];
        $auth['authMethods'] = [
             HttpBearerAuth::class
        ];

        unset($behaviors['authenticator']);
        $behaviors['authenticator'] = $auth;
          return array_merge($behaviors, [
            'corsFilter'  => [
              'class' => Cors::className(),
              'cors'  => [
                // restrict access to domains:
                'Origin'                           => static::allowedDomains(),
                'Access-Control-Request-Method' => ['GET','HEAD','POST','PUT','PATCH', 'OPTIONS'],
                'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' => false,
                'Access-Control-Max-Age'           => 3600,                 // Cache (seconds)
                'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' => ['origin','authorization', 'X-CSRF-TOKEN','X-Requested-With','X-Auth-Token','content-type'],
                'Access-Control-Request-Headers' => ['*'],
               'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' => []
              ],
            ],
            'verbs' => [
                'class' => \yii\filters\VerbFilter::className(),
                'actions' => [
                    'Stock_Interne_API' => ['POST','PUT'], // Only allow POST requests for the 'webhook' action
                ],
            ],
          ]);
          return $behaviors;
  }

  protected function verbs()
  {
      return [
          'index' => ['GET', 'HEAD','POST','PUT'],
          'view' => ['GET', 'HEAD'],
          'create' => ['POST'],
          'update' => ['PUT', 'PATCH'],
          'delete' => ['DELETE'],
      ];
  }

  public function actions()
  {
      //  Yii::$app->response->statusCode = 200;
        $actions = parent::actions();
        //$actions['create']['prepareDataProvider'] = [$this, 'prepareDataProvider'];
        // disable the "delete" and "create" actions
      //  unset($actions['delete'], $actions['update'], $actions['index']);
         unset($actions['create']);
         unset($actions['update']);
         unset($actions['index']);
         unset($actions['view']);
        return $actions;
  }
  public function actionIndex(){
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

     $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

    return 'ok';
  }  public function actionView(){
      \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

       $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

      return 'ok';
    }
    public function actionCreate(){
      \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

       $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

      return 'ok';
    }
  public function actionUpdate(){
    \Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON;

     $data = Yii::$app->request->post();

    return 'ok';
  }


}
```

i would first to be able to get the correct return from the controller, then i will check what data i get and at last work on the function to update the stock on the yii2 app, but i need to be able to receive the data from the webhook before ^^

Comment: There are different possible causes. You need to check that the token, you've passed in `Authorization` header, makes it to the `findIdentityByAccessToken()` method. If it does than either your token is wrong or your implementation of that method is wrong. If it doesn't make it there then check that your authorization header contains `Bearer` and not `bearer` scheme. And, that the content of authorization header is passed to php processor. It might not be passed by default if you are using php fpm or some reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i've tried several things and did not find the solution, but, as it works with other apps i work for, i think i did something wrong. I will delete my code and do it again.